# How do I tell GCC not to link with the runtime library and the standard library?

Tags: c++, gcc

I passed the following commandline arguments to GCC:

```
gcc -e _main -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -fno-exceptions -nostartfiles -fno-rtti -g C:\ntdll.cpp
```

It gave me the following error:

```
/ cygdrive / c / Users / ---- / AppData / Local / Temp / ccDrwTbB.o: In function `main':
C : \users\nabeel\desktop / ntdll.cpp:5 : undefined reference to `__main'
C : \users\nabeel\desktop / ntdll.cpp:5 : (.text + 0x9) : relocation truncated to fit : R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__main'
collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

```
//ntdll.cpp:
int main() 
{
}
```

GCC version 4.9.3 on Windows (Cygwin)

Comment: If you *only* want to skip linking, you don't need this whole stuff. `-c` alone is enough.

Comment: @deviantfan I don't want to skip linking, I want it to not link to the CRT.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you use `-nostartfiles` option? With that option, you need to define your own `__start` entry which prepares the environment and calls the main function.
Remove the option `-nostartfiles` and try again.
See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

As I understand, you need to tell gcc not to link with runtime library `-nostdlib` and standard library `-nodefaultlibs`

> One of the standard libraries bypassed by `-nostdlib` and `-nodefaultlibs` is `libgcc.a`, a library of internal subroutines that GCC uses to overcome shortcomings of particular machines, or special needs for some languages. (See Interfacing to GCC Output, for more discussion of `libgcc.a`.) In most cases, you need `libgcc.a` even when you want to avoid other standard libraries. In other words, when you specify `-nostdlib` or `-nodefaultlibs` you should usually specify `-lgcc` as well. This ensures that you have no unresolved references to internal GCC library subroutines. (For example, `__main`, used to ensure C++ constructors will be called; see collect2.)

Comment: What I am asking is that why isn't `-e _main` doing its job and selecting `main` as the entry point?

Comment: Though removing `-e _main` and changing `main` to `__start` works.

Comment: Where do you find `-e ` option, this page doesn't list it https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: @Danh It's a option for the ld linker

Comment: @deviantfan it's an option for ld linker, he need to use `-Xlinker option` to pass it to linker.
P/S: I don't have my working machine here to test.