GCC | My least possible C code size if 15KB and i can't change it
I can't reduce the size of my executable no matter what i do.
I have an empty Untitled-15.c file, which contains only:
int main(){return 0;}

I compile the code with following lines:
gcc Untitled-16.c -o RuTT2.exe -Os -s | the File size is 15KB
strip RuTT2.exe | The size is still 15KB! (same thing with g++)


But when i try to use some header files, i get the same size, even though they've been linked to my exe:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    write(1,"Hello world!", 12);
    printf("je");
    Sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}


Compile:
gcc Untitled-16.c -o RuTT2.exe -Os -s | 15KB
strip RuTT2.exe | 15KB


I tried different combinations of linker options, but the file size is always either equal or more than 15.360 bytes (15KB).
Did anyone faced with this problem? How to make the gcc output file less than 15KB?
P.S:
GCC version: 13.2.0.
Platform: Win10 x64
P.P.S: Sorry for misunderstanding. I used Os as gcc linker flag, not 0s.
P.P.P.S: a file with WinMain and linker flags -nostdlib as entry point breaks the 15kb barrier (4KB with flags i mentioned and 3kb with some new). Thanks to everyone who helped me to resolve this problem.

You should remove the c++ and g++ tags as they are not used in your post.  C++ is not C, the C language doesn't have overloaded functions nor exceptions.

Don't use printf with constant text.  Use puts or fwrite.  The printf statement has a lot of stuff associated (such as format conversions).  Remove or replace the printf for a smaller version.

I suspect your Win10 x64 platform has about 15KB of startup code for your program.  That seems like a reasonable and reasonably small size for the startup machinery.

The Sleep function may add some overhead to your program.  You don't need it.

There's just some runtime overhead. There are probably options that let you create a more barebone output, though -- but unless you know what you're doing you probably don't want that. As for the rest: the functions are likely in a DLL, which doesn't add much to the executable size.

@ThomasMatthews I am sorry if it's so, but i have this problem in both c++ and g++ as well.

You can probably shrink it a bit if you don't link with the runtime library. Of course then you won't be able to use those functions and you'll need to manually set the entry point. Why does this concern you?

@ThomasMatthews The purpose of the "Sleep()" line i added is in showing that 15KB is not the true size of this exe.

Tell the compiler to generate a map file, will all the details and options.  A common feature of a map file is to show all the functions in the program, their sizes and maybe their starting addresses or offsets.  This will allow you to identify the largest function and then maybe you can focus on reducing that.

"i have this problem in both c++ and g++ as well." you can ask a question about c++ as well. Or you can ask a question about C and see if the answer applies to C++ as well. Though, asking for C and C++ while only showing the C code is asking for two answers at once while only providing half of the details in the question. Consider that questions are supposed to be useful for future readers, and someone only interested in C++ will be disappointed to see only C, and vice versa

How to create tiny PE (Win32) executables using MinGW may help.

The example command lines look like they are using -0s (digit zero) when the proper optimization option is -Os (letter O).

Read up on the gcc command line switches.  Some compilers wiil pack in a standard library whether you use it or not; to speed up the build process.  For example, build in release mode; debug mode packs in symbol information.

How to make the gcc output file less than 15KB?  Why?  What will that gain you, or what problem will that solve - if it's even possible?

@RetiredNinja Thanks! Now i at least know that the executable may be generated under 15kb in my gcc compiler. Gotta do some research now, thanks again!

You need some startup code and on hosted system it will be dificult to have less that this 15k as the proper startup process is quite complicated.

It can be a fun exercise making things as small as they can be but it can be a bit of a double edged sword too. One of my colleagues wanted to make our launcher/installer as small as possible. He used all the tricks and it was tiny, but that also made it more likely to be flagged by heuristic virus detectors since most of what it did was to download another program and run it, just like a virus downloader would. Code signing helped a bit with that but did make it bigger. shrug

Have you tried -nostdlib and -nostartfiles? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237029/how-do-i-tell-gcc-not-to-link-with-the-runtime-library-and-the-standard-library

A trip down memory lane: 15k executable! I recall making a 5-byte program called reboot.com that had 1 5-byte instruction: jump FFFF:0000 (or something like that).

Use strip --strip-unneeded. Check sections sizes with objdump --headers.

@chux-ReinstateMonica My reboot.com was just CD 18. Also there was two-byte exec.com: EB 80 which executes arbitrary code encoded in command line argument and placed in PSP.

@chux-ReinstateMonica Here

@ThomasMatthews "Don't use printf with constant text. " gcc is smart enough to detect such statements and replace them with puts().
